# 16.04: Change increments of time to move forward or backward with Videos AKA Totem

Tags: 16.04, video, time, totem

In [Videos](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) AKA Totem in Ubuntu 16.04, on pressing the right arrow key the video is forwarded by 1 minute and pressing the left arrow key, the video goes back by 15 seconds. How do I change this? I want to go forward by 15 seconds on pressing the right arrow key and backward by 10 seconds on pressing the left arrow key..

Answer (score 0):

```
                Bare key        with Shift     with Control
Left arrow      -15sec          -5sec          -3min
Right arrow     +1min           +15sec         +10min
```

Hope this helps.